# Add data set to tuple in python

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a data tuple called data_frank which contains biodata. In the data tuple, there is a data set containing work experience. The data :

```
data_Frank = ("Sydney", "03-03-1990", {"Tax Consultant", "Financial Officer", "Financial Policy Manager"})
```

I want to add work experience = "Chief Financial Officer" in the data set.
How do I add work experience to a data set in a tuple?

the output like this

```
("Sydney", "03-03-1990", {"Tax Consultant", "Financial Officer", "Financial Policy Manager", "Chief Financial Officer"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the work experience tuple element elements with the element index `data_Frank[2]` and then add a new element to your set with the `add` method

```
data_Frank[2].add("Chief Financial Officer")
```